# Should I use Base64 encoding or byte[] for returning binary data in .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, binary, arrays, base64

I have a simple question. Should I return a byte-array or simply base64 encode my binary data, when exposing it through a web service in .NET?
Is there any pros/cons with either method, which is mostly supported etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use byte array. Over a SOAP protocol this byte array will automatically be serialized using base64 encoding. Your web service will be also more descriptive if you use a byte array. Imagine someone who wants to consume your web service and looking at a method whose signature looks like this:

```
string GetBinaryImageFromDatabase();
```

He might wonder why does this method returns a string and what am I going to do with this string, while if it returns a byte array it is much more clear.

I've seen web service method that look like this:

```
string SaveCustomer(string customer);
```

Guess what the `customer` and the return types were: they were some proprietary XML. There's absolutely no sense of using SOAP if people reinvent protocols over it.

Comment: Interesting points. I'll discuss this with the other members of my team, to see if they have any objections :)

Answer (score 0):

One consideration is that a Base64 encoded string enables you to use the "Test Form" to help debug any issues, etc. The Byte array is a complex type and therefore the test form will not work.

Comment: But the content of the encoded string still would be a byte array. If I need to debug, I could always call Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] inArray).

Comment: Yes, my point is purely that in order to call/test your method you will need to build a test harness that passes/receives a byte array. If you use a base64 string then you can call your webmethod manually without writing a test harness.