# Different ways to return image data in C# & Angular2

Tags: c#, angular

Has this been recently discussed after release of Angular2?

my api secured backend point is in C# and client is in Angular2. The server is returning byte[] for images and using base64 in Angualr2 code to display images

```
<img [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+user.photo" />
```

What other alternatives do I have to return my images without having to base64 encoding? And which is faster and Secure? I don't have physical paths to image in my server, only binary data in DB.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2521837/1019042) comparing between byte[] and base64, but it is dated since 2010 and not talking about performance impact.

Comment: If `user.photo` can be a URL instead of the image data itself, that shouldn't make a difference to Angular.  You'd just get rid of the `data:...` stuff before it in the `src` attribute.  That URL can simply be a server-side action which accepts an identifier for the image to be displayed, which would query the DB based on that identifier and return the image.

Comment: odd, is there a reason for doing it this way VS a specific action for images or just urls?

Comment: In my case, I am returning bunch of photo-related objects, that will also include an id, username, age, etc... I wanted to do it all in one DB hit